# Do Apps like Google Assistant work on Blloc Zero18?

Tags: applications

Do Apps like Google Assistant work on Blloc Zero18?
Because this is a minimalist phone with its own UI

Answer (score 0):

**Optionally.**

From [the Blloc site](https://www.blloc.com/)

> Start your smartphone experience differently with Blloc: the real (non-Google) stock Android experience *without any forced Google services*.
>
> Zero18 comes with the Blloc MNML operating system—a distraction-free custom software built on top of Android 8.1

So out of the box there appears to be **NO** Google Services.

Google Assistant, Google Maps, Google Mail, Google Translate all require Google Services to be running on the device.

Therefore from the Blloc help/wiki page: it seems you would need to [manually install Google Services](https://wiki.blloc.com/getting-started/installing-google-services) (basically flip a special settings switch and reboot) so that the device could get Play Store apps.

I'm unclear/doubtful that some of the deeper integrations of Google Assistant like being able have the phone passively listen for "wake words" to enable a voice assistant would be possible on this device.

You have the option to [use alternatives to Google Services](https://wiki.blloc.com/getting-started/no-google-alternatives)